# WPF 3D Performance - How can I make this faster

Tags: wpf, 3d

I am new to WPF3D. I am trying to figure out if wpf3d would work for my need.
To test, I wrote a simple program that renders around 15,000 spheres to the scene. When I run my test in Release mode, it takes about 30 seconds for the scene to show up and after that each frame takes about 3 seconds to draw. am I doing something wrong ? or is 15000 spheres too much for WPF to render. Any help is greatly appreciated. My Test code is posted below.

public Simple3DSceneInCode()
        {

```
        Title = "Simple 3D Scene in Code";

        // Make DockPanel content of window.
        DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
        Content = dock;

        // Create Viewport3D for 3D scene.
        viewport = new Viewport3D();
        dock.Children.Add(viewport);

        // Create the camera.
        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(new Point3D(-20, -20, -20), new Vector3D(20, 20, 20), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 45);
        viewport.Camera = cam;

        ModelVisual3D modvis = new ModelVisual3D();
        modvis.Content = new AmbientLight(Colors.Gray);
        viewport.Children.Add(modvis);

        modvis = new ModelVisual3D();
        modvis.Content = new DirectionalLight(Colors.Silver, new Vector3D(2, -3, -1));
        viewport.Children.Add(modvis);

        Model3DGroup geogroup = new Model3DGroup();
        MeshGeometry3D sphereGeom = GenerateSphere(new Point3D(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 0.3, 25, 25);
        DiffuseMaterial d1 = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Green);
        DiffuseMaterial d2 = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red);


        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 25; k++)
                {
                    GeometryModel3D sphereMode = new GeometryModel3D();
                    sphereMode.Geometry = sphereGeom;
                    sphereMode.Material = d1;
                    sphereMode.BackMaterial = d2;
                    sphereMode.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D((double)i / 2.0, (double)j / 2.0, -(double)k / 2.0);
                    geogroup.Children.Add(sphereMode);
                }
            }
        }

        ModelVisual3D mvgeom = new ModelVisual3D();
        mvgeom.Content = geogroup;

        viewport.Children.Add(mvgeom);

    }



    MeshGeometry3D GenerateSphere(Point3D center, double radius,
                                  int slices, int stacks)
    {
        // Create the MeshGeometry3D.
        MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

        // Fill the Position, Normals, and TextureCoordinates collections.
        for (int stack = 0; stack <= stacks; stack++)
        {
            double phi = Math.PI / 2 - stack * Math.PI / stacks;
            double y = radius * Math.Sin(phi);
            double scale = -radius * Math.Cos(phi);

            for (int slice = 0; slice <= slices; slice++)
            {
                double theta = slice * 2 * Math.PI / slices;
                double x = scale * Math.Sin(theta);
                double z = scale * Math.Cos(theta);

                Vector3D normal = new Vector3D(x, y, z);
                mesh.Normals.Add(normal);
                mesh.Positions.Add(normal + center);
                mesh.TextureCoordinates.Add(
                        new Point((double)slice / slices,
                                  (double)stack / stacks));
            }
        }

        // Fill the TriangleIndices collection.
        for (int stack = 0; stack < stacks; stack++)
            for (int slice = 0; slice < slices; slice++)
            {
                int n = slices + 1; // Keep the line length down.

                if (stack != 0)
                {
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 0) * n + slice);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 1) * n + slice);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 0) * n + slice + 1);
                }
                if (stack != stacks - 1)
                {
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 0) * n + slice + 1);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 1) * n + slice);
                    mesh.TriangleIndices.Add((stack + 1) * n + slice + 1);
                }
            }
        return mesh;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't intend to change the GeometryModel3D objects after creation, then you could "freeze" them.

```
public void Simple3DSceneInCode()
{
    Title = "Simple 3D Scene in Code";

    // Make DockPanel content of window.
    DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
    Content = dock;

    // Create Viewport3D for 3D scene.
    var viewport = new Viewport3D();
    dock.Children.Add(viewport);

    // Create the camera.
    var cam = new PerspectiveCamera(new Point3D(-20, -20, -20), new Vector3D(20, 20, 20), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 45);
    viewport.Camera = cam;

    ModelVisual3D modvis = new ModelVisual3D();
    modvis.Content = new AmbientLight(Colors.Gray);
    viewport.Children.Add(modvis);

    modvis = new ModelVisual3D();
    modvis.Content = new DirectionalLight(Colors.Silver, new Vector3D(2, -3, -1));
    viewport.Children.Add(modvis);

    Model3DGroup geogroup = new Model3DGroup();
    MeshGeometry3D sphereGeom = GenerateSphere(new Point3D(0.2, 0.2, 0.2), 0.3, 25, 25);
    sphereGeom.Freeze();
    DiffuseMaterial d1 = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Green);
    DiffuseMaterial d2 = new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 25; k++)
            {
                GeometryModel3D sphereMode = new GeometryModel3D();
                sphereMode.Geometry = sphereGeom;
                sphereMode.Material = d1;
                sphereMode.BackMaterial = d2;
                sphereMode.Transform = new TranslateTransform3D((double)i / 2.0, (double)j / 2.0, -(double)k / 2.0);
                sphereMode.Freeze();
                geogroup.Children.Add(sphereMode);
            }
        }
    }

    ModelVisual3D mvgeom = new ModelVisual3D();
    mvgeom.Content = geogroup;

    viewport.Children.Add(mvgeom);
}
```

Comment: Hi colinsminth, that really helped. The initial creation time went from 30 seconds to about 4 seconds. thank you. The draw still takes about 3-4 seconds. Is there any thing I can do to bring that down?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two resources I found helpful:

[Optimizing 3D Collections in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timothyc/archive/2006/08/31/734308.aspx)

[Maximizing WPF 3D Performance on Tier-2 Hardware](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/15/maximizing-wpf-3d-performance-on-tier-2-hardware.aspx)